# Representation theory Regular representation

Tags: representation-theory

I need help parsing this question and could use some hints. Show that if $G$ is a finite group, then its regular representation is self dual. I know that the regular representation over $\mathbb{C}$ is $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(V)$, where $V$ is spanned by $\{ e_{g} \}_{g \in G}$ and $p(h)(e_{g}) = e_{hg}$. I am not sure what self-dual means. I am assuming that $\rho$ is equal to its dual representation, which is defined by $\rho' :  G \rightarrow GL(V')$, given by $\rho'_g(e'_{k})\left[ \rho_{g}(e_{h}) \right] = e_{k}'(e_{h}) \implies \rho'_g(e_{k}'(e_{h})) = e'_{k}(\rho_{g^{-1}}(e_{h}))$, but how do I show these representations are equal?

Comment: I believe you mean $\rho'_g(e_k') = e_k'\circ\rho_{g^{-1}}$ as your last equation. You need to show that $\rho$ and $\rho'$ are *isomorphic* (rather than equal) as representations, meaning that there exists an isomorphism $\Phi:V\to V'$ such that $\rho'_g\circ \Phi = \Phi\circ\rho_g$ (in this case, $\Phi$ is often called an *intertwining map*). Can you think of a possible candidate for $\Phi$ in this case? There's really just one possibility.

Comment: Besides what @user17945 said, there's another approach of showing this using character theory, if you have already seen it.

Comment: @user17945, I think the only map is $\Phi : V \rightarrow V'$ defined by $\phi(e_{k}) = e_{k}'$ is it.

Comment: Yeah, that's it.

Comment: @user17945 I am stuck as to why $\Phi$ is an intertwiner. So $\rho_{g}^{*} \circ \Phi = \Phi \circ \rho_{g} \implies \rho_{g}^{*} \circ \Phi (e_{k}) = \Phi \circ \rho_{g} (e_{k}) \implies  \rho_{g}^{*} e_{k}' = \Phi(e_{gk}) \implies \rho_{g}^{*} e_{k}' = e_{gk}' \implies \langle e_{gk}' , e_{gk} \rangle = \langle e_{k}' , e_{k} \rangle$. I am just a little lost, could you explain why $\Phi$ is an intertwiner?

Comment: Your first three implications are actually iffs, so we just need to prove $\rho_g^*e_k' = e_{gk}'$. Applying to an arbitrary $e_h$, $(\rho_g^*e_k')(e_h) = e_k'(\rho_{g^{-1}}e_h)= e_k'(e_{g^{-1}h}) = \delta_{k,g^{-1}h} = \delta_{gk,h} = e_{gk}'(e_h)$. Since this holds for all $e_h$, it implies that $\rho_g^*e_k' = e'_{gk}$, and so $\Phi$ is an intertwiner.